# Nvidia GPU giving poor performance on 20.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 20.04, nvidia-prime, nvidia-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with RTX 2060 on my laptop.
Nvidia driver version - 440

My problem is that whenever I select **NVIDIA (Performance Mode)** in the PRIME PROFILES, my Ubuntu starts lagging. My screen is 144Hz but it feels a lot like 50ish something. I also tried running DOTA2 but poor fps there (30-35),

I started exploring, and I stumbled on nvidia-smi.
After running the command `nvidia-smi -q --display=POWER`, I am getting the following output:

```
Timestamp                           : Thu May  7 02:49:21 2020
Driver Version                      : 440.64
CUDA Version                        : 10.2

Attached GPUs                       : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : N/A
        Power Draw                  : 2.79 W
        Power Limit                 : N/A
        Default Power Limit         : N/A
        Enforced Power Limit        : N/A
        Min Power Limit             : N/A
        Max Power Limit             : N/A
    Power Samples
        Duration                    : Not Found
        Number of Samples           : Not Found
        Max                         : Not Found
        Min                         : Not Found
        Avg                         : Not Found
```

What is shocking is that my **Power draw is 2.79W**, which I believe is extremely low for GPUs.

Can please someone help in getting this to work? I've been at this for hours.

Comment: I see five, count them, (5) different 440-series drivers for Linux at NVIDIA https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx . May I suggest you try their latest driver and retest? https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/159360/en-us

Comment: Doesn't help. Anything else that might help?

Comment: For troubleshooting purposes, step back and try 418.113 https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/153717/en-us

Comment: Please post the output of nvidia-smi with no options.  That at least will include the device name -- it probably is not the 1060.  What does lspci list for device 01:00.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

try 'max preformance'. My desktop performance improve a little. I believe NVIDIA don't support Linux well.

[image]